# How to create a share button for whatsapp, facebook or others app installed in my phone

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am developing an app, where I want to share the TEXT and IMAGE to other apps installed on my phone.
But when I click the share button Neither it shares TEXT nor IMAGE just empty it directs me to another app I chose for sharing.
below **postDescription** and **postImage** are my methods of model class, and I checked that am I getting values are not in a toast it gives there values properly.

**Below is the code:**

```
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
                shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                shareIntent.setType("image/*");
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, postDescription);

                Uri uri = Uri.parse(postImage);
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share With"));
```

So the above bunch of code was not working, then I found code through which I can share my post TEXT and IMAGE to WhatsApp only, I tried that but it shows **file formate not supported** inside WhatsApp.

**below is the code for sharing to WhatsApp only:**

```
  Uri imgUri = Uri.parse(postImage);
            Intent whatsappIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            whatsappIntent.setType("text/plain");
            whatsappIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
            whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, postDescription );
            whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imgUri);
            whatsappIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
            whatsappIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

            try {
                context.startActivity(whatsappIntent);
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {

                Toast.makeText(context, "Whatsapp have not been installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

I want to know how to create a share button that works fine for WhatsApp and everything or only WhatsApp will do the work for me.

Answer (score 0):

By removing the package from the intent, Android should display the list of apps that can handle the type of intent.

```
Uri imgUri = Uri.parse(postImage); //Provide the URI to the downloaded image, not an external URL
Intent whatsappIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
whatsappIntent.setType("*/*");
whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, postDescription );
whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imgUri);
if (whatsappIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
    startActivity(whatsappIntent)
}
```

Comment: Enric Thank you for adding an answer, I tried your answer and share a post via Gmail only text shows image not loaded. please any suggestion

Comment: Are you providing the actual URI of a downloaded image or just a URL? If you are providing an external URL you should first download the image and then add it as attachement.
+ you are setting two times the mimetype.
Find my answer updated

Comment: First I upload my photo to firebase storage, then download the URI and store to  Firebase Realtime to a  child called postimage. then from there I am getting that URL through model class not downloading...but it's URL was once downloaded from storage.

Comment: You need to provide a local storage uri. If you are using firebase you can check this info out:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url
storageRef.child("users/me/profile.png").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
    @ Override
    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
        // Got the download URL for 'users/me/profile.png'
    //CREATE YOUR INTENT WITH THIS URI
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @ Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
    }
});